# Listen for Network change - Ionic 2

Tags: angular, cordova, ionic2, cordova-plugins, ionic-native

I need to monitor network change and do action in my Ionic 2 Mobile application. For that I used the network module of Ionic.

```
$ ionic cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-network-information
$ npm install --save @ionic-native/network
```

But it always shows a warning like

```
18:29:51]  console.warn: 'Native: tried accessing the Network plugin but it's not installed.
[18:29:51]  console.warn: Install the Network plugin: 'ionic cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-network-information'
```

Still, on running the Application and switching the network, it is not working as expected. Below is my code

```
// watch network for a disconnect
    let disconnectSubscription = this.network.onDisconnect().subscribe(() => {
      console.log('network was disconnected :-(');
    });

    // watch network for a connection
    let connectSubscription = this.network.onConnect().subscribe(() => {
      console.log('network connected!');
      if (this.network.type === 'wifi') {
        console.log('we got a wifi connection, woohoo!');
      }

    });
```

On disconnect, no action is performed. On connecting agin, the disconnect listener got triggered followed by connect listener. Below is the console.

```
[18:30:15]  console.log: network was disconnected :-(
[18:30:16]  console.log: network connected!
[18:30:16]  console.log: we got a wifi connection, woohoo!
```

In few forums, it said that it is a bug with Ionic 2. Is it that real ? How to monitor the network change if not this way. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Add code into platform ready. Once your app is running

```
let disconnectnet = Network.onDisconnect().subscribe(() => {
  console.log('you are offline');
  });

let connectnet = Network.onConnect().subscribe(()=> {
 console.log('you are online');
 });
```

Now disconnect and connect your network on check your console if you are facing Network plugin but it's not installed. issue then by using ionic cordova plugin rm cordova-plugin-network-information if this command is not work then you can manually remove network plugin just remove cordova netowrk form config.xml and package.json and also remove cordova network folder from plugin folder then install by using ionic cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-network-information

Comment: My Cordova version is 8.0.0

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to remove & add the platform again. Sometimes Ionic gets in a inconsistent state with plugin configuration/installation and this usually resolves it.

`ionic cordova platform rm <platform>`

`ionic cordova platform add <platform>`